# Config::set and Artisan::call

Tags: laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

Every time I run this command below, it runs on the default database, note the database I've selected:

```
Config::set('database.connections.mysql.database', 'somedatabasename');
Artisan::call('migrate');
```

Anyone know what this is not working?

Comment: what does the error it throws ?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement that by using different environments. For example, one config for testing environment, another for local / staging / production. Could you elaborate on what you're actually trying to achieve and what's the context so we can answer in more depth?

Comment: i`m trying to make a multi-tenant app with separated database for each tenant, so this line of code above will be responsible to migrate the database to the tenant. the tenant will have your own subdomain like "tenant.myapp.com", my app get the subdomain name, which is in fact the user name and set the necessary configs for the tenant.